# Ubuntu and a Epson Artisan 835 printer not installing (Install locks up)

Tags: drivers, 14.04, printing, epson

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and a [Epson artisan 835 printer](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?sku=C11CA73201) not installing (Install locks up).

I use set-up, printers, and choose the Epson. It starts to install and locks up about half way.

Is there a way to install it in through bash and how would I do that?

Comment: Can you add details do you get any error message?

Comment: No errors just stops with the install bar in the middle.

Comment: I might also mention iv let it run for 4 hours with no progress.

Comment: I press cancel with no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

Ensure you have updated your system apt databases:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To avoid potentially destroying your dpgk database from a botched install, ensure the following package is installed: dpkg-dev

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

Then, instead of using the printer tool, search for your epson driver with apt:

```
sudo apt-cache search EPSON Artisan
```

For me, I selected the artisan 725 - 835 series driver:

```
sudo apt-get install epson-inkjet-printer-artisan-725-835-series
```

Open up the printer configuration tool:

Ubuntu -> System -> Printers (or type printers in the search bar if you are running ubiquity)

Add a printer (mine is wired in on the network and shows up within 30 seconds)

Select your printer and since the driver is already installed, it will ask you for the printer details (location/name) and then open up the test printer dialog. All is now OK.

The graphical installer through the tool for the driver does not seem to work.